# Move files on set count of 300 to a new folder with a sequence name with in the same folder

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am looking for a way to sort of the files.
I have a folder which contains 100000 files is JPG.
I want to run a batch file on this folder which would Create a Folder for Every 300 File and store the 300 files in it.

1 Folder - 300 Files
2 Folder - 300 Files.
..
32 Folder - 300 Files.

I want to Script on execution to Create a Folder with Random Name Once it Scan thru 300 File and Put all the 300 Files in that folder.

I am not good with the complex part of batch procession , but I managed to list the files, but now I have to make a count on the files till its 300 and then make a folder and store it and go for the next count..

Please let me know if anyone can help with it.

Thank You.

Regards,
Sheldon

Answer (score 1):

Test this on some sample files:  You can change `300` to `50` to sort into batches of 50 for example.

The `folder prefix` is not guaranteed to be unique but it may work ok for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=999
set prefix=%random%%random%
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
set /a c=c+1
set /a d=c %% 300
if !d! equ 0 set "f=%prefix%-!c!"&md "!f!"
move "%%a" "!f!" >nul
)
echo moved
pause
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Hi,This work like a charmed.. Thank you for the solutions..great help and quick

Answer (score 0):

The subfolders get numbered from `0...x`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
CD /d "Folder100000"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('DIR /b /a-d ^|FINDSTR /n $') DO (
    FOR /f %%c IN ('SET /a %%a/300') DO (
        ECHO MD %%~c 2>nul
        ECHO MOVE "%%~b" %%~c
    )
)
```

Replace `Folder100000` with your folder name and remove the `echo`s.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: If sequential is set to a numeric, will generate sequential directories starting at #assigned.
:: If sequential is set to nothing (no characters between '=' and '"') will generate random names
SET "sequential=0"
SET "sourcedir=u:\test"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" ^|findstr /n /r "." ') DO (
 SET /a dest=%%a %% 300
 IF !dest!==1 CALL :newdestdir
 REM Next line for testing. Will simply display proposed move.
 ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%b" "!destdir!\"
 REM Next line for operating. Will execute proposed move if REM is edited-out
 REM MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%b" "!destdir!\" >nul
)

GOTO :EOF

:newdestdir
SET "destdir=%sourcedir%\%random%"
IF DEFINED sequential (SET /a sequential+=1&SET "destdir=%sourcedir%\%sequential%")
IF EXIST "%destdir%" GOTO newdestdir
MD "%destdir%"
GOTO :eof
```

You'd need to set your source directory and choose whether you want to create sequential directorynumbers or random. Either way, if a directory already exists, it will be skipped and the next directorynumber selected.

You'd need to remove the `rem` from the indicated line to actually perform the move after verification. The previous `ECHO` line could be `REM`med-out or removed if you don't want a display.